# Sum on Count in hql - error Not yet supported place for UDAF 'count'

Tags: hql

I'm new here so please be gentle, my first question after using this website for a long time regards the below:

I'm trying to create a sum of count of events in the past 30 days:

```
select  key, sum((COALESCE(count(*),0)))
from table
Where date>= '2016-08-13'
And date<= '2016-09-11'
group by key;
```

but the sum doesn't seem to work. i'm looking at the last 30 days, and i would like to count any row that exists for each key, and then sum the counts (i need to count on a daily basis and then sum all day's count).

If you can offer any other way to deal with this issue i'm open for suggestions!

Many thanks,
Shira

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest aggregate functions in HQL (or SQL).  However, if you just want a count of records falling within range for each key, then you can simply just use `COUNT(*)`:

```
select  key, count(*)
from table
where date >= '2016-08-13' and
      date <= '2016-09-11'
group by key;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was a couple things wrong with your code.
I've written this for you, haven't tested it but it passes the syntax test.

```
SELECT COUNT(key) AS Counting FROM tblname 
WHERE date>= '2016-08-13'
AND date<= '2016-09-11' 
GROUP BY key;
```

And [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) might help you. You should definitely be using COUNT for this query.

I'm not sure if it's related but there might be an issue with calling a field 'key' I kept receiving syntax errors for it.

Hope I was able to help!

-Krypton